# Strange issue with repeater and cached dataset - only last row shown

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching, dataset, repeater

I have a relatively simple piece of code as follows:

```
        Dim oShow As DataSet = Nothing
        Dim cacheKey As String = String.Format("AsyncCacheFor_agenda_{0}", ShowID)

        If Not IsNothing(Cache(cacheKey)) Then
            oShow = DirectCast(Cache(cacheKey), DataSet)
        Else
            oShow = DataServers.dsTMW.GetAgenda(ShowID, 0, "", 0, True)
            Cache.Insert(cacheKey, oShow, Nothing, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0))
        End If
        phSearch.Visible = True


        oShowRow = oShow.Tables(0).Rows(0)


        oTracks = oShow.Tables(1)
        oSearchResults = oShow.Tables(5)


        If Not IsNothing(oSearchResults) AndAlso oSearchResults.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            rptSearch.Visible = True
            phNoResults.Visible = False
            rptSearch.DataSource = oSearchResults
            rptSearch.DataBind()
        Else
            rptSearch.Visible = False
            phNoResults.Visible = True

        End If
```

"rptSearch" is a `Repeater` and the `GetAgenda()` method reads a dataset from the database via stored procedure. This dataset has 6 different tables. When the dataset is read from the database, the `Repeater` displays 36 rows, the expected result. When it's read from the cache it only displays one row, the last one. What's strange is that when I debug, I see that `oSearchResults.Rows.Count = 36` in both cases.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

Comment: could you provide the code for the repeater?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was doing this in the ItemDataBound event:

```
Dim dvRows As DataView = oSearchResults.DefaultView
dvRows.RowFilter = String.Format("Submission_id={0} AND speaker_id Is Not Null", oRow("Submission_id"))
```

Once I changed that to:

```
Dim dvRows As DataView = oSearchResults.Copy().DefaultView
```

The problem went away. I wonder why this was only a problem when it was being cached.

Answer (score 0):

To truly see if it has anything to do with the cache, try always using the Dataset from the cache. On the check to see if it is in the cache, rather than going and getting the Dataset and then using it, go get it, put it in the cache, then use it.

So, rather than this:

```
If Not IsNothing(Cache(cacheKey)) Then
    oShow = DirectCast(Cache(cacheKey), DataSet)
Else
    oShow = DataServers.dsTMW.GetAgenda(ShowID, 0, "", 0, True)
    Cache.Insert(cacheKey, oShow, Nothing, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0))
End If
```

Do this:

```
If IsNothing(Cache(cacheKey)) Then
    oShow = DataServers.dsTMW.GetAgenda(ShowID, 0, "", 0, True)
    Cache.Insert(cacheKey, oShow, Nothing, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, New TimeSpan(1, 0, 0))
End If

oShow = DirectCast(Cache(cacheKey), DataSet)
```

This won't "fix" your issue, but it will narrow down the isue. If you get 1 row always, then you know it has to do with pulling the Dataset out of the cache. If I had to guess though, I'd say that there is something else going on outside of your code snippet.

Comment: Even with your code everything shows up the first time, but not after. But if I completely remove the caching everything shows up every time.